# Como eu transfiro a responsabilidade de um ponteiro?

Tags: c++

Durante a implementação do design pattern Command, eu me deparei com o seguinte dilema:

"Como eu sinalizo para os clientes de uma determinada classe, que o ponteiro passado como parâmetro será destruído?".

Para exemplificar essa situação, segue abaixo a classe RemoteControl e seu uso pelos clientes da classe.

Digamos que a classe RemoteControl possua um vector de ponteiros para comandos.
Essa classe se responsabiliza por desalocar os ponteiros salvos no vector durante a redefinição e durante a destruição do objeto RemoteControl.

```
class RemoteControl {
private:
  vector<Command*> commands{7};
public:
  RemoteControl() {
    for(auto& cmd : commands) cmd = new NoCommand();
  }
  ~RemoteControl() {
    for(auto& ptr : commands) {
      if(ptr != nullptr) delete ptr;
    }
  }
  void set_command(int slot, Command* cmd) {
    if(commands[slot] != nullptr) delete commands[slot];
    commands[slot] = cmd;
  }
};
```

Dessa forma, é responsabilidade dos clientes da classe RemoteControl fazer a alocação dos
objetos Command, porém eles não devem fazer a desalocação, pois uma vez que um comando
é passado para a classe RemoteControl, a classe "toma posse" do ponteiro.

Eu desconfio que a assinatura do método `set_command` deva mudar, para receber xvalues.
Mas eu nunca usei e nem vi isso com "raw pointers".

Talvez uma assinatura do tipo

```
void set_command(int slot, Command* && cmd)
```

Para que os clientes utilizem a classe RemoteControl da seguinte maneira:

```
int main()
{
  Command* cmd = new Command();
  RemoteControl* remote = new RemoteControl();

  remote->set_command( 0, std::move(cmd) );
  remote->set_command( 1, new Command() );
    
  delete remote;
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Eu acho que essa historia de eu criar e ser outro a destruir é propicia a erro e meio complicada. Se eu crio o comando fora da classe então devia ser eu a destruir. Acho que passar o controlo do ponteiro a outra classe só complica no exemplo que você tem. Posso imaginar mais cenários complicados como fazer uma duas atribuições seguidas do comando. Nesse caso quem destroi o primeiro comando? 
De qualquer forma se quiser mesmo fazer pode no minimo passar uma função no `set` que sirva de callback para executar sempre que você vai iniciar a destruição do ponteiro.

Comment: Certo. Deixa ver se eu entendi. O mais correto a se fazer seria escolher um desses dois objetos para ter a responsabilidade de criar e destruir?

Comment: Mais do que isso. O princípio que os programadores de C costumam seguir é quem constrói também destrói. Quando se segue essa filosofia fica fácil de controlar e não esquecer coisas com vazamentos em memória. Quando isso não acontece tipicamente fica difícil de controlar. Não quer dizer que não possa fazer diferente, mas como vê é mais complicado, e não é o padrão.